# How can i set panel in ng2-map?

Tags: angular

Please provide any plucker example to set panel using ng2-map

I am able to set markers with directions but i am unable to set panel my div 
tag like [this Google maps Panel](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/directions-panel)

It gives InvalidValueError: setPanel: NaN
I followed :[this reference](https://rawgit.com/ng2-ui/ng2-map/master/app/index.html#/directions-renderer)

```
<ng2-map [hidden]="!checked" zoom="13" [center]="origin">
    <marker *ngFor="let pos of positions" [position]="pos"></marker>
    <directions-renderer
      [suppressMarkers]="true"
      [draggable]="true"      
      (directions_changed)="directionsChanged()"
      [directions-request]="direction"
      [panel]="directions-panel">
    </directions-renderer>
  </ng2-map>
  <button (click)="positions = showRandomMarkers()">Show Random Markers</button>
  <button (click)="positions = showDirection()">ShowDirections Markers</button>
   <br/>
   <div [hidden]="!checked" id="directions-panel" style="width: 28%; float:left; height: 450px; overflow: auto; padding: 0px 5px"></div>
```

Comment: did you find a solution ? i have the same problem